# Drupal: How can one use Context to trigger a reaction for a Taxonomy Term condition caused by a View?

Tags: drupal, view, taxonomy

What I would like to do is use the Context module to insert $body_classes of my choosing based on a Taxonomy Term condition.  Fine, that's what the Context module is for.  Seems simple enough IF your content/page source is a node that is involved with the appropriate Terms.  However, I have a page generated by Views that has the appropriate Taxonomy Term id that SHOULD trigger the condition but it doesn't.

Now I could set my $body_classes in a "preprocess" in template.php but I'd rather avoid that.  Is this even possible in Context?  Or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth here is my two cent :
When working with drupal modules, I have found that when i know a module (or combination of modules) is almost doing what i need, and i try and push them to the limit, i find myself wasting far more time trying to make the modules do that "x" feature, than it would take to code my own simple little module.
So for "edge cases", when it looks abvious that you need a very complexe setup/config to achieve something (if you ever can achieve it with the mods in hand, just go and code your own little custom module.